# How to make face normals permanent and not change when I Flip normals?

Tags: faces, normals

How can I make it so after flipping some normals they "stick" and don't revert back to their original orientation when I recalculate with <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>N</kbd>?

Comment: You cannot make them stick to a certain position when using Shift+N, because it calculates the normal orientation based on what seems to be the actual outside/inside of the mesh. So there is no arbitrary setting to be taken into account, it is always automatically geometry-based. With Alt+N you can manually flip normals so they are not calculated according to the geometry, but that's all.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

But isn't "set from faces" actually that? It's not so much about having SHIFT+N "fixing normals in place" rather than just keeping what the custom normals orientation has been set to and ignoring auto orientation based on geometry and keeping as it is just before hitting SHIFT+N. Feels to me that's not really "out there" and could come in handy in certain situations.

Comment: No, _Set from Faces_ has nothing to do with flipping face normals to a desired orientation. This is used in combination with _Auto Smooth Shading_ and sets custom normals at corners (not faces) to the normal of the face it belongs to. As the **from** faces part suggests, you take a normal from a face and assign it to something else.

Comment: Here is just a quick example of what the _Set from Faces_ option does, I've enabled split normals (purple) and face normals (cyan) in the overlays so you can see the change. I selected two faces and then used _Set from Faces_, afterwards the split normals on the selected face corners are only pointing in the according faces direction or averaged between the two of them if a corner belongs to both: [normals > set from faces](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AzmCC8uIjykQ0OtE89UqjEdKZ0CKp_XN/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: And to reset a set from face would require an average > face normal correct?
Since SHIFT+N is only for faces, doing that wouldn't do anything to the split / normals set from faces. Got it, thanks.